# Distiller-option in TeXShop: Ghostscript vs. Apple Distiller

Tags: pdf, conversion, editors, output

Today I noticed that in the last panel of the TeXShop options I can choose between `Ghostscript` and `Apple Distiller` as the "Distiller" of my Document.

[image]

Any pros and cons for these alternatives? Is there any difference in quality, font embedding, file-size, available and supported PDF-features, microtype stuff, etc.?

I am using the `lualatexmk` engine. Is this engine already deciding for me, i.e., would it change anything at all if I edit the options of TeXShop?

Comment: Close voters: could some comments be left explaining? There seems to be a pretty clear TeX link here to me.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/Preferences-of-TeXShop-td623762.html

Comment: Could you edit in some info about your set up, _e.g._ OS X version, TeXShop version and perhaps a screen shot? For me (OS X 10.9.1, TeXShop 3.26), I see 'Ghostscript' and 'Apple Distiller' on the 'Misc' tab of 'Preferences'.

Comment: @JosephWright : oh... you're right. That was a false friend. Sorry for the confusion. I meant `Apple Distiller`. Nonetheless, the questions stands as it is. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Your question still says Adobe in the headline even though your detailed version now specifies Apple. Perhaps you could correct the former as well?

Answer (score 7):

If you are generating the PDF by LuaTeX directly, then the distiller options are not relevant. They matter, if PostScript is generated (e.g., TeX generates DVI and dvips converts it to PostScript). Then there are differences between Ghostscript and Adobe Distiller.

Some features of Adobe Distiller are not supported by Ghostscript:

- Some conversion options, see [`Ps2pdf.htm`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/gnu/6.53/Ps2pdf.htm).
- For example, package `accsupp` has to write some `pdfmark` specials in the page stream for the `/ActualText` feature. However, these specials are not supported and therefore ignored by Ghostscript.

Comment: The actual preference distinguishes between the Ghostscript distiller (`ps2pdf`) and the Apple distiller (`pstopdf`). I don't think there is a commandline version of the Adobe distiller available for the Mac, and it's certainly not accessible via the TeXShop preferences. (I actually think this is still a useful answer, but I don't think it directly answers the question.)